# How to zero the coefficients of a signal below the cut-off frequency using a pywavlet?

Tags: python, signal-processing

I'm currently using pywavlet on python to break down 1kHz signals into 'db8' and 10 levels to zero certain frequency bands (0-0.25Hz, 250-500Hz).
However, when the signal is decomposed, the signal in the approximation area is expected to be 0 to 0.488 Hz, and at this time, the signal in the 0 to 0.25 Hz area is expected to be 0. What should I do?
Also, I would like you to tell me how to apply soft rigrsure thresholding.

```
LEVEL = 10
WAVELET = 'db8'
PAD = "sym"

coefficients = pywt.wavedec(sig, WAVELET, mode=PAD, level=LEVEL)

coefficients[0][:] = 0
coefficients[LEVEL][:] = 0

result_sig = pywt.waverec(coefficients, WAVELET, PAD)
```